# Change the handler to avoid click pressed twice requirement - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have in my project the following handler:

```
let  btnHandler = () => {
      if (date1 && date2) {
      refetchAll(events.options.all.variables);console.log("win-win");
      console.log(date1,date2);
}}
```

I want to modify this code (no need second braces), so it will do the same, but will require only one button click:

```
let  btnHandler = () => 
      if (date1 && date2) {
      refetchAll(events.options.all.variables);console.log("win-win");
      console.log(date1,date2);
}
```

The problem, that I don't know how to do it. In current state this handler requires from me a twice press click on Button to get an effect, result and data. I have a table which reads data from GraphQl, and in above handler I send a refresh instruction. I need to press twice, So React will update table. If I will change the code to no braces - It gives me error:

```
./src/components/modules/reports/Reports.js
  Line 366:4:  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  364 |
  365 | let  btnHandler = () =>
> 366 |           if (date1 && date2) {
      |           ^
  367 |           refetchAll(events.options.all.variables);console.log("win-win");
  368 |           console.log(date1,date2);
  369 | }
```

I've tried:

```
let  btnHandler = () =>
      refetchAll(events.options.all.variables)|setmyVar|SetState|action1|action2;
      console.log(date1,date2);
}
```

But this doesn't work. I do not understand what is doing arrow function, and why arrow function works immediately and prefect. But how to link to one button click multiple actions? Other ideas what I thinked about are: promises, await, useContext. I am novice in js and React (just 2-3 month hardly working).

Upd, my Button code:

```
<Button onClick={btnHandler}>Search</Button> - need pressed twice
<Button onClick={() => refetchAll(events.options.all.variables)}>Search</Button> // Works fine! Only one time press requires.
```

But in - `<Button onClick={() => refetchAll(events.options.all.variables)}>Search</Button> //I need to add more instruction. Like:`

```
<Button onClick={() => refetchAll(events.options.all.variables)|SetMystate|Dosometh1|Dosomething2}>Search</Button>
```

Comment: What do you mean "so it will do the same, but will require only one button click:"?

Comment: I do mean:<Button onClick={() => refetchAll(events.options.all.variables)|console.log("smthing"}> - works. Check the chat please I send there a lot examples.

Comment: Why do you want to remove 2nd  braces. It seems https://xyproblem.info/

Comment: Updated the question, also trying to use the answer given below. Sorry, but you doesn't give any useful advice. It's easy to send a user to url, instead of giving a method or other options. I am novice and might be miss some requirements, this is why asking advice.

Comment: Sorry, you didn't give any clear question. It's easy to scribble  something on SO and help for useful advice.

Comment: I've stuck on this thing about a week, and tried to learn everywhere and googled my issue a lot and after came to SO. I am near to cry and close to become a zombie, cause I need to finish that project in time - in beginning of March. Exactly in the case, if it would be plain JS I used to be use an addeventlistener to button - and no problem with twice actions. But in React I don't have a knowledge, because I think here everything is async.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My mistake was that I used normal JS variables, instead of React **useState**. So variables in my case should be:

```
const [date1, setDate1] = useState(new Date);
etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems like You are missing { } character after the declaration of function btnHandler, just add that character:

```
let btnHandler = () => {
  if (date1 && date2) {
    refetchAll(events.options.all.variables);
    console.log("win-win");
    console.log(date1, date2);
  }
}
```

this is how to link to one button click multiple actions

```
// Example

import React from 'react';

function App() {

  function greeting() {
    console.log('hello!');
    waveHello();
  }

  function waveHello() {
    console.log('');
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={greeting}>
        I'm a button
      </button>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: OP already has this btnHandler as shown in a question, and s/he said "I want to modify this code (no need second braces), so it will do the same," I'll be surprised if OP accepts this answer.

Comment: I am asking for a method. Not just to remove a bracers. I am asking for redo, remake my code - so app will accept several action in one click.